# get the url from asp:HyperLinkColumn

Tags: vb.net

I have a HyperLinkColumn on datagrid. I need to get the DataNavigateUrlField from for loop. I know how to get the text from asp:label control using it's id. Would someone tell me how to do it.

there is my dragrid:

```
     <asp:DataGrid id="MyDataGrid" 
       BorderColor="black"
       BorderWidth="1"
       GridLines="Both"
       AutoGenerateColumns="false"
       runat="server">

     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#aaaadd"/>

     <Columns>

        <asp:HyperLinkColumn
             HeaderText="Select an Item"
             DataNavigateUrlField="IntegerValue"
             DataNavigateUrlFormatString="detailspage.aspx?id={0}"
             DataTextField="PriceValue"
             DataTextFormatString="{0:c}"
             Target="_blank"/>
       <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type"   />
     </Columns>

  </asp:DataGrid>
```

My code:

```
 For Each item As DataGridItem In MyDataGrid.Items           
        Dim cell As Hyperlink = CType(item.Cells(0).Controls(0), Hyperlink)
 Next
```

Comment: Are you looking for the [HyperLink.NavigateUrl Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.navigateurl?view=netframework-4.8.1)? It appears to me that that could work as long as converting the control to a Hyperlink works.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I got the error"  Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'Hyperlink'

Comment: If there is more than one item in `item.Cells(0).Controls`, perhaps you could debug it to find out if the data you need has a different index instead of `(0)`.